# Theme keeps going to default files

Tags: templates, customization

Theme files go back to default, deleting my custom templates I have created.

I have a back-up, but it does it once a day.

Anyone run into this before, is it a backup issue?

Comment: what do you meant by theme goes back to default?? Is it your own theme or did you modified some theme??

Comment: edited one, and then it erases my templates I am making

Comment: so must be you have edited theme wrongly..... otherwise wordpress will not set default theme automatically...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're editing the theme directly it might be because of an update, when a them updates it deletes all the changes you have made on it.

If you want to edit themes you have to create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Just create a folder next to your actual theme folder (*wp-content/themes*) with the name you want for your child theme and create the style.css file with the **Template** option of your [stylesheet header](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet) pointing to your actual theme (write there the name of your actual theme folder).

To make any changes just copy teh page you want to modify from your theme folder to your child theme folder and edit it there.

That way the changes will remain after the update

Comment: thanks this is great, I'm sure it was because of the version, that it keep updating when I would put it back, now I just installed it in a new folder and edited css to remove version and template url.  

thanks for the idea